# iOS: Detect memory constraints before allocating objects

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, didreceivememorywarning

Is there a technique for avoiding undue memory consumption by testing the availability of memory before it's allocated?  I understand that the general iOS approach is to optimize memory usage and respond to didReceiveMemoryWarning when necessary, but sometimes that doesn't cut it.

In my use case (image processing), I'm allocating space for a (potentially) large image using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext().  If the image is too big, I eventually get a didReceiveMemoryWarning.  But, it's too late at that point:  from a user experience perspective, it would've been better to prevent the user from working with such a large image to begin with; it would make more sense to say, "Sorry!  Image size too big!  Do something else!" before creating it than to say, "Ooops!  Crashing now!"

I found a few SO threads on querying available memory and/or total physical memory, but using them is a messy and unreliable solution:  there's no way to tell how much memory the OS is actually going to let you use at a given point in time, regardless of how much is free.

Basically, I want these semantics: (in "Swift-Java-ese")

```
try {
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGRect(x: reallyBig, y: reallyBig))
}
catch NotEnoughMemoryException {
   directUserToPickSmallerImage()
}

// The memory is mine;  it's OK to use it
continueUsingBigImage()
```

Is there a methodology for doing this in iOS?

Comment: Re exceptions: In iOS exceptions are reserved for programming non-recoverable errors. Technically there is a problem with recovering across stack frames. You might try pre-flitting with `NSData dataWithBytes:length:` and check for nil.

Comment: Oh, I didn't literally mean to throw an exception -- I just meant success/immediate failure semantics. (Sorry! That was confusing...) The NSData idea might work, but it requires using malloc which you can't do in swift.

Comment: Maybe the better way to go is to restrict your app to handle a max size and bit depth.  The max image from the current device's camera seems like a reasonable restriction.

Comment: I should have said: `NSMutableData length:`, see my answer. Malloc is not explicitly called and under the covers malloc is called for most heap allocations even in Swift.

Comment: @danh - I did consider that, but I'd like to avoid hard constraints, if possible.  Two devices with the same camera can have different amounts of memory installed. And the number of open apps comes into play.  And I'd need to update the constraints for future devices.  I'd like to stick with something dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try pre-flitting with `NSMutableData` `var length: Int` and check for nil.

```
let data: NSMutableData? = NSMutableData(length:1000)
if data != nil {
    println("Success")
}
else {
    println("Failure")
}
```

Comment: Ok, that could work... but how do I know iOS isn't going to want that memory back later? And if it does, how do I explicitly free it?

Comment: It has the same lifetime as any other variable depending on how it is declared, a local or a ivar. If you want to control the lifetime more closely, you probably do, use an `autoreleasepool { }`. If the example was wrapped in an `autoreleasepool` the allocation would be made and released at exit of the scope.

Comment: When there are no retains remaining for an allocation it is released at the end of the closest enclosing `autoreleasepool` which usually it the run loop. By adding your own you can more carefully control the release. This is handy when making large temp allocations inside one run loop. (Hotel WiFi is bouncing like crazy making it really hard to post.)

Comment: @AnnaDickinson could you share the final code you used? I am trying to do the exact same thing and I was wondering if you released the NSMutableData variable before you actually started the UIGraphicsBeginImageContext() code. If not, how did you use the NSMutableData var in your Graphics code?